# Verbose flag error from caer.preprocess_from_dir

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am following a OpenCV course and I am following along with how to make a program that detects Simpsons characters with deep learning, but when I try and create the learning data I get a verbose flag error.

```
import os
import caer
import canaro
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import gc

IMG_SIZE = (80,80)
channels = 1
char_path = r'C:/Users/glett/OneDrive/Documents/simpsons_dataset'

char_dict = {}
for char in os.listdir(char_path):
    char_dict[char] = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(char_path, char)))

# sort in descending order
char_dict = caer.sort_dict(char_dict, descending=True)

#get top 10 characters
characters = []
count = 0
for i in char_dict:
    characters.append(i[0])
    count += 1
    if count >= 10:
        break

#creating training data, grabs character images
train = caer.preprocess_from_dir(char_path, characters, channels=channels, IMG_SIZE=IMG_SIZE, isShuffle=True)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\glett\OneDrive\Desktop\porgam\python\simpsons_example.py", line 30, in <module>
    train = caer.preprocess_from_dir(char_path, characters, channels=channels, IMG_SIZE=IMG_SIZE, isShuffle=True)
  File "C:\Users\glett\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\caer\preprocess.py", line 64, in preprocess_from_dir
    raise ValueError('verbose flag must be either 1 (display progress to terminal) or 0 otherwise')
ValueError: verbose flag must be either 1 (display progress to terminal) or 0 otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value of verbose in `caer.preprocess_from_dir()`, `verbose = 1`, if you want to see how your machine is training the model and if you don't then put `verbose = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one line missing.

```
characters = []
count = 0
for i in char_dict:
    characters.append(i[0])
    count += 1
    if count >= 10:
        break
characters --> you missed this line
```

you could try